# Simple PDO query works on dev server but not in production. Why?

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following PDO query which works fine on the development server but on the live server, returns an empty result set.

An identical copy of the database exists on both servers and there are no error messages in either httpd or mysql logs. Neither is there any PDO exception.

```
<?
class DB {

  public function __construct() {

    global $dbh;

    try {
      $dbh  = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=snomweb_main', 'snomdb_user', '6pjOjYpcRpEZFdsu');
      $dbh  ->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

  public function getFAQCats2Array() {

    global $dbh;

    try {
      $q = '
                                SELECT
                                        `id`        AS ci,
                                        `name`      AS n
                                FROM
                                        `faqcat`;
                        ';

      $s = $dbh->query($q);

      // initialise an array for the results
      $A = array();

      if ($s->execute()) {
        while ($r = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $A[] = $r;
        }
      }
      $s = null;
      return $A;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo  "Something went wrong fetching the list of FAQ categories from the database.\n";
      file_put_contents(
                        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/PDOErrors.txt",
                        "\n\n\n\n".$e->__toString(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
  }
}
```

(There were other functions in the file, but I've removed them for simplicities sake)

The method is being called like this:

```
<?
require_once '../inc/classes/db.class.php';
$DB = new DB();

$cArr   = $DB->getFAQCats2Array();
$qArr   = $DB->getFAQQuestions2Array();

foreach ($cArr AS $c) { // do this for each group ?>

<h3><?=$c['n']?></h3>

<div>

    <? foreach ($qArr AS $q) { // do this for each question in group

        if ($q['ci'] === $c['ci']) {
    ?>

    <a href="faq-answers.php?i=<?=$q['qi']?>" title=""><?=$q['q']?></a><br>

    <?
        } // end 'if'

    } //  /do this for each question in group
    ?>


</div>

<? } //  /do this for each group ?>
```

The code is building a jQuery accordion, which is completed and works perfectly in the development environment, but on the live server, it's getting an empty array returned instead of containing the 9 FAQ categories.

The production server is using PDO on other websites and is running MySQL Server version: 5.0.37-standard.

The development server is running MySQL Server version: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log - (Ubuntu).

The collations are both `utf8_general_ci`. Both using InnoDB tables.

Comment: you have a class, and class has members why your using `global`

Comment: I don't think this will correct your problem, but you don't have to call `$s->execute()` on the result of a `$pdo->query()`

Comment: Since the query doesn't have a `WHERE` clause, I can't think of any reason for this other than the table being empty in the live server.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I removed the `if` statement completely and it solved the problem! Perhaps you could put this in a question for me, so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Another simplification: your `fetch` loop is equivalent to calling `fetchAll()`.

Comment: @PeterSnow ok, going for it

Comment: `execute` is for prepared statements, not statements that have already been executed with `query`. The surprising thing is that it worked in dev.

Comment: @PeterSnow out of curiosity, which PHP versions did you have in your dev environment and your live server?

Comment: @DevZer0 +1 for the heads-up. I tried various ways of initiating it as a `protected` variable but couldn't make it work. I'll ask another question shortly on how it should be written.

Comment: @PeterSnow on the `global $sdh`, inside your class when trying to make it protected, were you using it like `$this->sdh->query(...)` or without the `$this` part? In php, contrary to Java or C#, you have to specify `$this` always to access class methods/properties.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós The MySQL versions are included at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Barmar +1 for the heads up also. Will look into `fetchall`.

Comment: The issue isn't the mysql versions, it's the PHP/PDO versions.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. PHP is `5.2.9 (cli)` on the server and `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)` on development.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I experimented with a number of different ways with `$dbh` as a `protected` variable. I tried using `::` and `$this` but failed to get it working. I'm going to create a question about that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a `$pdo->query($sql_statement)`, the return value is a valid `PDOStatement` that you can iterate directly to fetch your results, don't need to do your `$s->execute()` sentence.

So just remove that :)